# Drop down list in java script

Tags: javascript, html

I have done a drop down lists using for loop in java script. How can i  take the values from every list and add it together and show the result in a text area.

This is what I have now:

```
list1.onchange = function()
{
    document.getElementTagId("input").value = list1.option[list1.selectedIndex].value;‌​
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i have try.. list1.onchange = function()
{          document.getElementTagId("input").value=list1.option[list1.selectedIndex].value;}

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding code in comments.

Comment: Can you also share an example of your html code? And I am sure there is some code missing in your javascript.

Comment: var list1 = document.createElement("select");

       for(var u=0; u<=20; u++)
       {
             var w= document.createElement("option");
             var e = document.createTextNode(u);
             w.appendChild(e);
             list1 .appendChild(w);          

       }
        

        list1.onchange = function()
        {
            document.getElementTagId("input").value=list1 .option[list1 selectedIndex].text;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Markup

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option>First</option>
    <option>Second</option>
    <option>Third</option>
</select>
<textarea id="textarea"> </textarea>
```

Javascript

```
 document.getElementById('dropdown')
    .addEventListener('change', function () {
       console.log(this.value);  
        document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML += this.value;
    }, false);
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaasthana/yX4Pr/). Hope this helps.

Answer 2:

After you updated your question,

```
var list1 = document.createElement("select"); 
for(var u=0; u<=20; u++) { 
    var w= document.createElement("option"); 
    var e = document.createTextNode(u); 
    w.appendChild(e); 
    list1 .appendChild(w); 
} 

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(list1);

list1.onchange = function() { 
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value=list1.value; 
}
```

You didn't add the list1 to the document body. Thats why you couldn't see the result.